# Sine LUT VHDL wont simulate below 800 hz

Tags: midi, vhdl, lookup-tables, trigonometry

I made a sine LUT for VHDL, using 256 elements.

Im using MIDI input, so values range 8.17Hz (note #0) to 12543.85z (note #127).

I have another LUT that calculates how many value must be sent to my 48 kHz codec in order to play the sound (the 8.17Hz frequency will need `48000/8.17 = 5870` values).

I have another LUT that contains an index factor, which is `256/num_Values`, which is used to call values from the sin table (ex: `100*256/5870 = 4` (with integer rounding)).

I send this index factor to another VHDL file, which is used to calculate which value should be sent back. (ex:  `index = index_factor*step_counter`)

When I get this index, I divide it by 100, and call `sineLUT[index]` to get the value that I need to generate a sine wave at the desired frequency.

The problem is, only the last 51 notes seem to work for me, and I do not know why. It seems to get stuck on a constant note at anything below that frequency (<650 hz) , and just decrease in volume every time I try to lower the note.

If you need parts of my code, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Just guessing, I suspect your step_counter isn't going through enough cycles, so your index (into the sine lut) doesn't go through a full 360 degrees for the lower frequencies.

For anything more helpful, you'll probably have to post code.

As an aside, why aren't you using something more like a conventional DDS?  Analog Devices has a nice write-up on the basics: [DDS Tutorial](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/tutorials/450968421DDS_Tutorial_rev12-2-99.pdf)

Comment: Ah yes, i never thought about that. That makes sense as to why it is getting quieter at lower frequencies, its just reading small values from the sampled sine wave. I forgot my code sent out a reset every 20 ms to sync some i2c and audio codec issues.

Thanks.